# Expression for calculated member

Tags: ssas, mdx

How to get the data between two dates. I used the following expression:

```
(
   {[campaign].[campaign start date]:[campaign].[campaign end date]},
   [Measures].[sales]
 )
```

but it is giving null as result.

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you posted the full MDX you are using.

In the meantime, I'm guessing you need to put the time dimension into a filter (WHERE) and the measures onto rows or columns, with another dimension (just it's top-level member) present in order to return a single results cell:

```
SELECT {[Some other dimension].defaultMember} ON ROWS,
{[Measures].[sales]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [MyCube]
WHERE (AGGREGATE({[campaign].[campaign start date]:[campaign].[campaign end date]}))
```

Since the `WHERE` clause accepts only tuples, you have to use `AGGREGATE` to compress your date range from a set into a single item.

You can also try creating a calculated member and filter on that:

```
WITH MEMBER [Actual Time].[6th to 30th Nov 2006] 
AS 'Aggregate([Actual Time].[All Actual Time].[2006].[December].[6 December 2006] : [Actual Time].[All Actual Time].[2006].[November].[30 November 2006])', 
SOLVE_ORDER=0 
SELECT {whatever} ON ROWS,
{[Measures].[sales]} ON COLUMNS
FROM [MyCube]
WHERE ([Actual Time].[6th to 30th Nov 2006])
```

Comment: I had never seen your version of the where and I don't seem to be able to get it to run.  I have always done my as WHERE {[campaign].[campaign start date]:[campaign].[campaign end date]}

Comment: OK, let me ask....do you wish to see a list of several dates (between the start and end) with a measure value next to each one? Or do you want to see one single value which represents the total of all dates in the range?

Comment: My Scenario as follows : I have a dimension ( lets call it DimensionX) which has a start date and an end date . These two dates are linked to Time dimension. The requirement is to get the sales which happened between the start date and the end date. Fact table also has a relationship with the Time dimension, DimensionX has not relationship with the Fact table other than being linked to the Time dimension. Could you please let me know how to proceed with the same ?

Comment: i would like to see as single value as measure between the specified dates

Comment: I've edited my answer to include curly braces {} in the first MDX, and an alternative second bit of MDX. This works for me, to reduce a measure values within date range down to a single total.